# manual or custom installation from scratch

Tags: system-installation, xubuntu

Often, for work reasons, I have to create xubuntu virtual machines that I use for embedded development.
How can I (starting from an iso image and a blank VM) avoid installing things I don't need, such as libreoffice? On google I found no way to do a manual or custom installation.

Edit: I don't want and don't need to customize a *Live CD ISO*. I need a custom installation cd that installs on my hard disk the packages I decide.
I tried cubic, and he created a live cd for me, but not an installation cd.

Comment: hmm... but... a live system is a system used to install Ubuntu (or other OS)...

Comment: @mastupristi That'd be a customized Live CD - the Live CD and its installation tasks can be customized, if you customize them to install additional packages then it will install the additional packages.  I'm confused as to how the proposed duplicate doesn't solve the problem...?

Comment: @ThomasWard I followed the directions here <https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-create-a-custom-ubuntu-iso-with-cubic/> and some videos on youtube. I tried to start the created image, but it doesn't offer me the usual choice between "try ubuntu" and "install". It starts directly without the request of installation on hard disk.

Comment: Just double click on the (ubiquity) installer in the dash once the Live CD boots up. (Also, perhaps you need to boot your computer into Legacy BIOS instead of UEFI to see the "Try" / "Install" buttons as your initial options).

Comment: After you setup the virtual machine - install Ubuntu, remove everything that you don't need, etc. - you can create a copy of its folder (for VMWare it should be in `$HOME/vmware/`), then when you need a clean installation replicate the backup copy with a new name...